# How to change position/order of addon/extension in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

how to I change position/order of addon/extension in Firefox?

I'm using the latest version available.

Comment: Are you referring to the icons on the toolbar?

Comment: Yes, for example say the extension I use most frequently is at 5th position. How do I bring it to 1st.

Answer (score 5):

In Firefox 89:

- Right click the toolbar
- Click 'Customise Toolbar'
- Drag the extensions into your preferred order
- Click Done when finished

[image: customise toolbar screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the right side of the extensions section and find the 3 stripes icon and click it.
2. Go to "Customize" and click it.
3. Look at the top right section (the extensions section). Click and drag your extension icons to re-arrange the order.